# How to get all user properties of a google web app project

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google web app with execution set to "User accessing the web app". Upon launch the app creates a key with user's Google id and stores a variable in the script's user properties (code below:)

```
var id = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var prop = PropertiesService.getUserProperties()
prop.setProperty(id, "some-variable")
```

I have the following questions:

1. Is there a way to fetch all the keys stored in the script's user properties (to know who has accessed the app)? When I execute:

   Logger.log(prop.getKeys())

it only shows key with my (script owner) id.

2. Since properties has a limit of 500kb, how do I free up space by removing unwanted keys?

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getuserproperties)

> getUserProperties()

> Gets a property store that **only the current user can access**, and only within this script.

In other words:

**You cannot get the user properties of other users**

Solution:

**Use [ScriptProperties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getscriptproperties) instead of `UserProperties`:**

```js
function doGet() {
  var id = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var prop = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  prop.setProperty(id, "some-variable")
}
```

You can retrieve the properties by

- either manually running a function that logs the script properties
- or by going on `File -> Project Properties -> Script Properties`

Comment: Is the limit of 500kb per user?

Comment: Yes, it's mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas). There is also a limit for the maximum size per property and for the number of read/write operations.